# Using JQuery and AJAX for URL that has data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this simple link

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/update?id=${data.id}">Update</a>
```

The `${data.id}` is mapped in my controller,

```
map.addAttribute("data", data);
```

I dont want to use a link, I want to use jquery and AJAX for the reason of It will not refresh my whole page just a part in the page.

Instead, I will put an id to it for my javascript.

```
<a id="get-id">Update</a>
```

The problem is I do not know how to pass that `data.id` to the javascript file

Now in my javascript file

```
$('#get-id').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: ROOT_URL + '/update?id=${data.id}',            
        dataType: "text"
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#update-container').html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `data` attribute to store meta data with an element, like this:

```
<a id="get-id" data-id="${data.id}">Update</a>
```

You can then read that attribute in your click handler using the `data()` method:

```
$('#get-id').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: ROOT_URL + '/update',            
        data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
        dataType: "text"
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#update-container').html(data);
    });
});
```

> How about If they were multiple buttons using that id. Which wont work. So I will use a class. How will I implement that?

The pattern would be the same. You would loop through your data set to create the multiple `a` elements, grouped by a class:

```
<!-- in a loop -->
<a class="foo" data-id="${data.id}">Update</a>
```

The jQuery would be exactly the same, aside from the selector:

```
$('.foo').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: ROOT_URL + '/update',            
        data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
        dataType: "text"
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#update-container').html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: `data: { id: $(this).data('id') },`  'id' not 'data.id' ? explain this line pls.

Comment: No, as it's reading the `id` property from the `data` attribute on the element.

Comment: The `this` is the data.id?

Comment: `this` is the `a` element.

Comment: How about If they were multiple buttons using that id. Which wont work. So I will use a class. How will I implement that?